# How to print in Firestore emulator with AppEngine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I just switched over from Firestore in Datastore mode to Firestore Native and it doesn't let me print anything locally. My file system is similar to [this](https://github.com/smartninja/gae-2nd-gen-examples/tree/bf370dfaea3d3a9a140116931521db611db5435a/structured-app-firestore) using `run.py` to run Firestore emulator. The rest of my code runs fine and Datastore mode allowed me to print anything just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this app locally and on App Engine as well. It's working fine.

Only thing I have noticed that first print does not work (or works with delay) on both  local and cloud. However after few messages sent, first message appear as well. In the README.md it stands that it was tested only on MAC. I have done it on Linux.

If you have done any changes to the code that might be the reason.

I hope this will help!